# Exact Value of Infinite Sum $ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n}{n!(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Find exact value of the sum:

$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n}{n!(n+2)} $

We could manipulate as follows:

$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n}{n!(n+2)}  = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n(n+1)}{(n+2)!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n(n)}{(n+2)!} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n}{(n+2)!}$

The second term can be computed by integrating the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ twice:

$ \int (\int e^{x}dx) dx = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{x}^{(n+2)}}{{(n+2)}!}$

which we can rewrite as follows if we set $x=-1$:

$e^{-1}= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^{n}}{{(n+2)}!}$

As for the first term $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n(n)}{(n+2)!}$, any hints would be greatly appreciated, or perhaps if general direction is already incorrect in the first place?

Comment: $n+1$ isn't just $n+1$. It's also $(n+2)-1$.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, thanks! Seems like manipulating is the main problem for me, any particular impetus for why it must be $(n+2)-1$? Because the term $n+2$ appears in the original expression, allowing for cancellation and later exploitation of the telescoping series?

Comment: Exactly, see Gary's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{{(-1)}^n}{n!(n+2)} = \int_0^1xe^{-x}dx = \frac{e-2}{e}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite
$$
\frac{(-1)^k}{k+2} =  \frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{k+2} =\int_{0}^{-1}x^{k+1}dx
$$
Interchange integral and sum, you get an expression, solve the sum for $e^x$
$$
\int_{0}^{1}xe^xdx
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use
$$
\frac{1}{{n!(n + 2)}} = \frac{{n + 1}}{{(n + 2)!}} = \frac{{n + 2 - 1}}{{(n + 2)!}} = \frac{1}{{(n + 1)!}} - \frac{1}{{(n + 2)!}}.
$$
instead.